# Active form textarea value gets changed in before submit

Tags: validation, yii2

I have a form with textarea. I used [jquery.textntags](http://daniel-zahariev.github.io/jquery-textntags/) for facebook type mentions functionality which is working fine. But when I submit the form through ajax the textarea content changes. Below is the example:

```js
$('#wall-post-form').on('beforeValidate', function (event, messages, deferreds) {

    console.log('Before validate: '+$('#wallpostform-content').val());
    // prints Before validate: @[[2:contact:Daniel Radcliffe]] how are you?

}).on('beforeValidateAttribute', function (event, attribute, messages, deferreds) {

    console.log('Before validate attribute: '+$('#wallpostform-content').val());
    // prints Before validate attribute: @[[2:contact:Daniel Radcliffe]] how are you?

}).on('afterValidateAttribute', function (event, attribute, messages) {

    console.log('After validate attribute: '+$('#wallpostform-content').val());
    // prints After validate attribute: @[[2:contact:Daniel Radcliffe]] how are you?

}).on('afterValidate', function (event, messages) {

    console.log('After validate: '+$('#wallpostform-content').val());
    // prints After validate: @[[2:contact:Daniel Radcliffe]] how are you?

}).on('beforeSubmit', function () {

    console.log('Before submit: '+$('#wallpostform-content').val());
    // prints Before submit: @[[2:contact:Daniel Radcliffe]]iel Radcliffe]] how are you?
    return false;
});
```

As you can see that the textarea value get changes in `beforeSubmit event`. I am not able to understand why is this happening. Any idea?